# Cannot correctly refresh page using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a page, which allows the user to add/edit/delete database table.
The database staff, and add/edit/delete, all work fine.
However, in my AngularJS method, I add `location.reload()`, trying to refresh the page to show the updated table. Unfortunately, the database has been updated, but the page isn't.
If I press `F5` to manually reload, the result is right.  I don't use `route` in the page.
Just want a simple function, and it can automatically refresh after being updated.

Below is sample codes

```
$scope.add = function(){
  //add something in database
  //no problem of this part

  location.reload() //doesn't work
};
```

Comment: have you added $location as a service ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the $ and the location service to the controller

```
MyController($scope, $location){

 $scope.add = function(){  
    $location.reload();
 }
}
```

Comment: what does the browser says in the debug window ?